# How to use hook_theme and hook_block_view correctly

Tags: blocks

The following code works - the block_view calls the theme function and the correct variables get passed.

Is this the right way to use these functions when you have a block and you want it themed with variables and using a specific template?

Thanks,

```
function youtube_pull_block_view($delta = '') {

    switch($delta){

      case 'youtube_pull':
      $block['content'] = theme('popular_analytics', array('videos' => get_most_popular()));    
      break;
    }

return $block;
}

function youtube_pull_theme() {

return array('youtube_pull_listing' => array(
             'variables' => array('videos' => NULL),
             'template' => 'youtube-pull-listing',));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That code would be perfectly fine, if you define a theme function and use that theme function. In your case, the code is defining the youtube_pull_listing theme function, but using the popular_analytics theme function.

As for an example of `hook_block_view()` implementation that uses a theme function, see [user_block_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_block_view/7), which contains the following code.

```
  if (user_access('access content')) {
    // Retrieve a list of new users who have subsequently accessed the site successfully.
    $items = db_query_range('SELECT uid, name FROM {users} WHERE status <> 0 AND access <> 0 ORDER BY created DESC', 0, variable_get('user_block_whois_new_count', 5))->fetchAll();
    $output = theme('user_list', array('users' => $items));

    $block['subject'] = t('Who\'s new');
    $block['content'] = $output;
  }
  return $block;
```

The fact the theme function is using a template file doesn't make any difference for how the function is called. The only difference is that the variables declared in `hook_theme()` are the variables the template file will be able to access.

Keep in mind that, in Drupal 7, it is now preferable to return an array in `$block['content']`, in the same way [`blog_block_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21blog%21blog.module/function/blog_block_view/7.x) does.

```
  if (user_access('access content')) {
    $result = db_select('node', 'n')
      ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title', 'created'))
      ->condition('type', 'blog')
      ->condition('status', 1)
      ->orderBy('created', 'DESC')
      ->range(0, variable_get('blog_block_count', 10))
      ->addTag('node_access')
      ->execute();

    if ($node_title_list = node_title_list($result)) {
      $block['subject'] = t('Recent blog posts');
      $block['content']['blog_list'] = $node_title_list;
      $block['content']['blog_more'] = array(
        '#theme' => 'more_link',
        '#url' => 'blog',
        '#title' => t('Read the latest blog entries.'),
      );

      return $block;
    }
  }
```

The reasons why using `theme()` is bad are given in [theme() renamed to _theme() and should not be called directly](https://www.drupal.org/node/2195739), even if that change record refers to Drupal 8.

- It circumvents caching
- It circumvents defaults of types defined in `hook_element_info()`, including attached assets
- It circumvents the pre_render and post_render stages
- It circumvents JavaScript states information

Comment: Just removed the popular_analytics reference.  Ok, well thanks.  Will carry on as before...

Answer (score 1):

I would say it would be preferable to return a render array as opposed to rending the output in block_view. This would give other modules an opportunity to edit your modules output before it is rendered.

An example of doing it this way would be:

```
function youtube_pull_block_view($delta = '') {
    switch($delta) {
        case 'youtube_pull':
            $block['content'] = array(
                '#theme' => 'youtube_pull_listing',
                '#videos' => get_most_popular(),
            );
            break;
    }
    return $block;
}
```